# Add Meta as help venue on the on-hold/closed notice

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Nowadays, the closure message says:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#), please [edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#) or [leave a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#). *`{Why is Meta not here?}`*

**Ask Ubuntu**:
[image: ubuntu]

**Code Review**:


<kbd>[image: codereview]</kbd>

I think this should be applied globally with something like:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#), please [edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#) or [leave a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#). You can also open a support request {for reasons} on the [Relevant Meta Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240623/add-meta-as-help-venue-on-the-on-hold-closed-message#).

**Related:** [Can we make this meta site work for mentoring?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268779/1287812)

<sup>*Cross posted from [Oferecer suporte no Meta ao colocar uma pergunta em suspenso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2009/201).*</sup>

Comment: To leave a comment in your own post in most cases doesn't notify anyone. None of the actual options seem to help beginners with no affinity with the SE model. +1

Comment: @Math, do you think it'd be possible to implement something like this on a single SE site?

Comment: I really have no idea :-/